# How to boost a solr document at query time based on attribute value

Tags: solr, lucene

I want boost at query time all documents that have value user_id=2. Basically I want on the top of my results all the documents belonged to a specific user.
After looking at some Solr resources I ended up writing a query like, but it is not working properly.

/solr/public-main/select?q={!boost b=if(div(155623,user_id),2,1)}sometext&wt=json&indent=true&debugQuery=true

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the boost with a dynamic boost. Apply a boost query which will boost all the documents that match the query: `bq=user_id:2^4`. Adjust `4` to a suitable boost value depending on the rest of your boosts (if any in `q` or `qf`).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have a [function query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries) with fl=x,y,userexists:exists(query({!v='user_id:2'})) and then u can sort by `userexists` and then by score field.